# Tensorflow: Read CSV

Tags: tensorflow

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([csv_file_path], shuffle=False)
reader = tf.TextLineReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
filename = tf.decode_csv(serialized_example, record_defaults=[[""]], field_delim=',')

# Input
png = tf.read_file(filename)
```

I am reading from a `CSV` file with one Column.
I am getting the **following** `error`. 
`ValueError: **Shape** must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'ReadFile' (op: 'ReadFile') with input shapes: [1].`
Could someone tell me the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.read_file()` needs a scalar input (i.e., just one string), but the results of `tf.decode_csv` are coming back in a "rank 1" context, i.e., a 1-D list.  You need to dereference the results:

```
filename = tf.decode_csv(serialized_example, record_defaults=[[""]], field_delim=',')
filename = filename[0]   # <-- add this.
png = tf.read_file(filename)
```

For more detail, see the docs for [`tf.decode_csv`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/decode_csv) -- note that the return type is a list of Tensor objects.

Comment: Thanks :) I should have seen the `return` type.